# xml2::read_xml does not read an url that does exist

Tags: r, xml2

I would like to read the data from the url: `u <- "https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/ovdp?date=20210112"`

I have this code:

```
f <- xml2::read_xml(u)
```

At the same time, I receive this error message:

```
Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
Opening and ending tag mismatch: META line 3 and html [76]
```

How can I fix it? if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your code works fine on my pc. What happens if you use `read_html` instead of `read_xml`?

Comment: HTML ≠ XML. `xml2::read_xml` parses *XML*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it isn't html.

Comment: @AllanCameron I tried read_html and it does not work. When I use read_xml, the code runs and stops on this line reporting that error. However, when I run this command in the console window it works fine. Strange!

Comment: Is your package updated? The code works fine

Comment: @AllanCameron According to the error message OP posted it clearly looks like HTML. Of course you’re right that the URL OP posted resolves to XML data (at least for me, presumably also for you). Maybe OP is geoblocked or rate limited, and the server delivers an HTML 40x response.

Comment: @KonradRudolph maybe the OP is getting served an html 404 page from the server? - the link itself opens a type of xml (it doesn't have an xml declaration but does parse with read_xml)

Comment: @TomHoel just re-installed the xml2 package, but the error remains.

Comment: Can confirm it works for me too - URL resolves to XML-looking data and parses with read_xml. @Alex if you manually supply an encoding with `encoding="UTF-8"` does anything change?

Comment: @Dubukay thanks for suggestion! How can supply it, please? P.S. On my side it (read_xml) does not work still.

Comment: Try reading `?read_xml`

Comment: @Dubukay thanks for the suggestion: I change it to `f <- xml2::read_xml(u, encoding="UTF-8")` and now it works...

Comment: @Alex Lovely, I suspected it might be an encoding issue because that can differ across platforms. Glad it helped.